# Noda Time Unit Testing XML Error

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, nodatime

I am trying to setup a simple unit test using Noda Time. My code is:

```
public void ValidityPassedDate()
{
    FakeClock fakeClock = new FakeClock(SystemClock.Instance.Now);
    fakeClock.AdvanceDays(60);
    MyClass myObj = new MyClass(fakeClock); 
    myObj.Validity = "1";
    myObj.Date = SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()).LocalDateTime.Date;

    Assert.IsTrue(myObj.ValidityIsValid);
}
```

But I get this error when I try to build the test:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=----------(I erased this on purpose)'.

How can I solve this? What's missing? VS2013 point the error to the `FakeClock` type in `"FakeClock fakeClock =..."`

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Xml?

Comment: I tried to make a using System.Xml; but VS2013 says it can't find it

Comment: you need to add a reference in the project. Right click on the project references section, then choose Add Reference. On the left, under the section called "Assemblies" choose "Framework" then find "system.xml" and tick the box to the left then click "ok". The version number does sound odd. It wants version 2.0. What framework version are you targetting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a *reference* to the `System.Xml` assembly (not a `using` directive for the `System.Xml` namespace). Do that in Solution Explorer - it's not a code issue.

This is unfortunate, but as far as I can tell it's an unavoidable side-effect of Noda Time implementing XML serialization... presumably due to the attributes used to decorate the type.

Comment: Hey Jon - perhaps we could add the `<frameworkAssemblies>` tag in the nuspec?  ([docs](http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference))

Comment: @MattJohnson: Yes, that sounds like a good idea. Will add it to the issues list.